# Getting error on first line on pom.xml after I changed version from 2.5.2 to 1.4.7. I'm using spring boot 3.8.0 Release

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, spring-tool-suite

I'm new to sts. When I changed model version from pom.xml file line no 7(2.5.2 to 1.4.7). I got this error

> Failure to transfer org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.20 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the
> local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.
> Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.20 from/to central (https://
> repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Try on plain command line `mvn clean package -U` ...

Comment: @khmarbaise Where do I need to apply this command?

Comment: Read about maven goals, how maven pulls the dependencies and How you can update the dependencies using eclipse having the maven plugin configured.

Comment: As I wrote on plain command line....

Comment: You could also try a right click on the project, then `Maven -> Update Project...`. But running the build of the project from your command line first is definitely a good idea to see if that downloads the necessary artifacts.

Comment: Another side note: Your title mentions version 3.8.0 of Spring Boot, but I think you mean version 3.8.0 of the Spring Tool Suite. That is quite an old version, you should think about using the latest Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse distribution from https://spring.io/tools instead.